# iPhone SDK: Tell UIWebView not to load images and CSS just plain HTML and JS?

Tags: iphone, html, image, uiwebview

Is there any way to tell a UIWebView not to load images and CSS for faster rendering?

**Solution:** [URL filtering for UIWebView on the iPhone](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries. The first one says "if it is not an iphone, use the normal style sheet", the second says "if it is an iphone, implement style rule: don't display images" :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="not (max-device-width: 480px)" href="normalstyle.css">

<style type="text/css">
@media (max-device-width: 480px) {
     img {
       display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the server side. So I need to tell the UIWebView not to load the images. Is that possible?