# How to stop loading images in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, uiwebview

I want to use UIWebView to load a html url, but don't load the image in the html.I want UIWebView just display the plain text in the html. And because of some reason, I can NOT change the html content before loading.

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: can you provide that html string format

Comment: Maybe you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067943/iphone-sdk-tell-uiwebview-not-to-load-images-and-css-just-plain-html-and-js.

Comment: This may help you:

[stop loading images][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598833/stop-images-from-loading-in-uiwebview

Comment: @Narayana the html string format body part is something like <img src="some url" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    BOOL blockURL = [[FilterMgr sharedFilterMgr] shouldBlockURL:url];
    if (blockURL) {
        NSURLResponse *response =
              [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:url
                                        MIMEType:@"text/plain"
                           expectedContentLength:1
                                textEncodingName:nil];

        NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse =
              [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response
                             data:[NSData dataWithBytes:" " length:1]];

        [super storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];

        [cachedResponse release];
        [response release];
    }
    return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
}
```

It some part code from [this](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/)

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

```
Then remove all image tages using below code then after load your html string into webview


NSString *str =@"<ul><img src=\"some url\"/><li>Tiny pores in leaves or stems, which water and gas can pass. </li><li>Plants can reduce the amount of water that is passed by closing the stomates during the hottest parts of the day or curling their leaves up to reduce exposure.</li></ul>";
    NSLog(@"before--%@",str);
    NSRange r;
    while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<img[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"after---%@",str);
```

Comment: There are ways that an image can be loaded without a static img tag in the source, including via JavaScript and CSS.